# How to clear all plans from a single database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I want to clear out the procedure cache for just one database, not the entire SQL Server. Is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (<db_id>)
```

This command allows you to specify a particular database id, and then clears all plans from that particular database. Check more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293622.aspx).

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

This command removes all cached plans from memory

> It is, of course, recommended that you don’t use these commands on
>   your production servers, as it could impact the performance of your
>   running applications. Usually, you want to keep plans in cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used `SELECT DB_ID('<db_name>')` to get the database id.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to clear cache is to use [`DBCC freesystemcache`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56855/8783)

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('userdatabase') -- cleans cache for specific user database
```